# Use *ngFor in typescript file in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

Use *ngFor in typescript file in Angular 9

use *ngfor in typescript not in html file

```
async printString(orderObject) {
    let html = '';
    return orderObject.reduce(async (lastPromise: any, order: any, j: any) => {
        lastPromise;

        var date = order.timeStamp.seconds*1000;
        var orderDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy , h:mm a');

        html = html +
        `
        <table>
          <tr style="border: 0px">
              <td>
                <div> <img style ="height: 80px;width: 80px;" src= 'assets/icon/shivam64.png'> </div>
              </td>
              <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td><td></td>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td><td></td>
              <td>
                  <STRONG> Client Information </STRONG>
                  <div><STRONG>Mobile : </STRONG> +919826598620 </div>
                  <div><STRONG>Date : </STRONG> ${orderDate} </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>

        <table>
          <tr style="border: 0px">
              <td>
              <STRONG> Client Information </STRONG>
              <div> ${this.customerData.name} </div>
              <div> ${this.customerData.address} </div>
              </td>
              <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td><td></td>
              <td>
              </td>
              <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></td><td></td>
              <td>
                  <STRONG> Order Details </STRONG>
                  <div><STRONG>Order Id : </STRONG>${order.orderId}</div>
                  <div><STRONG>Delivered By : </STRONG>${order.creatorName}</div>
                  <div><STRONG>Collected By : </STRONG>
                    <span *ngIf="gasData.collectedBy">
                      ${order.collectedBy.name} -
                      (${order.collectedBy.contact})
                    </span>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>

        <br/>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <th>S.No</th>
              <th>Description of Gas</th>
              <th>Size</th>
              <th>Total Collected</th>
              <th>Total Delivered</th>
              <th>Total Volume</th>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <ul style="list-style: none;padding: inherit;">
                <li style="margin: 5px auto;" *ngFor="let orderData of order.totalDelivered; let last = last;">
                    ${j+1}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul style="list-style: none;padding: inherit;">
                <li style="margin: 5px auto;" *ngFor="let orderData of order.totalDelivered;">
                    <span [ngStyle]="{color: ${this.getColor(this.gasData.type)}}">
                        {{orderData.type}}
                    </span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      
        `
        return await html;
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }
```

[image: use *ngFor in typescript]

Good day, I am just wondering if it is possible to do the logic of *ngFor in the typescript? I want to loop the data in the typescript just like what *ngFor does in the HTML. Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What your are doing is an anti-pattern.
by using Angular, your component/service logic should not be responsible for the templating. Fetch the data and display it by using data binding in a component template.

Comment: You can't do that because of angular directives are supported only on templates

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question. You can use the `foreach` function or `for of` keywords.

Examples:

```js
const array = [3, 4, 5, 6];

array.forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem);
});

for (let elem of array) {
  console.log(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
Angular compiles the template + the ts file and produces plain html and javascript. You have to put the html in a separate file and interact with it from the ts file.

Comment: This is why i dislike the abstraction Angular invented for HTML templating. They're basically re-implementing a subset of Javascript features without the advantages. I'd prefer a function that renders HTML from state using JS/TS. Code in React is way shorter, no redundant abstractions.